# Swift function without argument labels

Tags: swift, syntax, swift3

Let's say I write the following function in Swift 3:

```
func rgb(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1)
}
```

When I call it, I must write `let black = rgb(r:0, g:0, b:0)`

Is it possible to write this function so that I can call it as `let black = rgb(0, 0, 0)`?

Comment: See the "[Omitting Argument Labels](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166)" section of the language guide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use an `_` to ignore the label:

```
func rgb(_ r: CGFloat, _ g: CGFloat, _ b: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1)
}
```

Arguments can have two parameter names, an external name followed by the internal name. An underscore (`_`) means 'ignore this value', so the external label isn't required at the call site.

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158):

> **Omitting Argument Labels**
>
> If you don’t want an argument label for a parameter, write an
>   underscore (_) instead of an explicit argument label for that
>   parameter.
>
> ```
> func someFunction(_ firstParameterName: Int, secondParameterName: Int) {
>     // In the function body, firstParameterName and secondParameterName
>     // refer to the argument values for the first and second parameters. 
> }
> someFunction(1, secondParameterName: 2)
> ```
>
> If a parameter has an argument label, the argument must be labeled when you call the
>   function.